# SSRS Math Ops Report Body..Aggregat functions can only

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm really struggling to find out the proper approach to adding (or other math operations) in the report body. Surely this is a daily operation done by report writers all over the world but I'm missing the boat.

I can add etc. fields from a dataset such as SUM(Fields!FieldA + Fields!FieldB).

However when I try to work with two textboxes in the report I get the Aggregate functions can  be used only on report items....blah. For example SUM(ReportItems!Textbox1 + ReportItems!TextBox2).

So how does one add two textbox values on the report body????

JB

Comment: Can't you just use `=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value + ReportItems!Textbox1.Value` without the `Sum`, assuming you're just adding values that have already been aggregated in the original textboxes? It's hard to say without being able to see where the textboxes are in the report and what underlying values they're displaying.

Comment: Wellllll...you're assuming I know what I'm doing. Being new I thought operations had to be passed into the functions so I was using SUM. However accessing directly as you indicate works perfectly. Change your comment to an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Ha ha, fair enough! Cool, that would be much appreciated; please see below. I also expanded the answer slightly, but if it's working now - great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value + ReportItems!Textbox1.Value` without the `Sum`, assuming you're just adding values that have already been aggregated in the original textboxes.

It's hard to say without being able to see where the textboxes are in the report and what underlying values they're displaying.

You can also consider using the exact same underlying functions in the source textboxes, e.g. if **textbox1** is the total of **value1** in **DataSet1** and **textbox2** is the total of **value2** in **DataSet2**, you could use something like:

`=Sum(Fields!value1.Value, "DataSet1") + Sum(Fields!value2.Value, "DataSet2")`